# How to make \xrightleftarrows and \xleftrightarrows longer?

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to reproduce this text in Latex

[image]

On the left you see what I could achieve by now, with the following LaTeX code:

```
\polyring{\mathbb R}{x}_{/\ideal{x^2+1}}\mathrel{\mathop{\rightleftarrows}^{\mathrm{\alpha}}_{\mathrm{\beta}}} \mathbb C
```

Where `\polyring` and `\ideal` are defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\polyring}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\big[#2\big]}}
\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1\rangle}}
```

Instead on the right you see the result I'd like to achieve. I couldn't find anything that would satisfy my needs. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a double arrow doesn't exist in `amsmath`, but the `extpfeil` package provides one under the name `\xtofrom[under]{above}`.

I took the liberty to redefine your `\ideal` command with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools`. Last the mathrm version of greek letters doesn't exist (unless you use a font such as `fourier` which defines them), but you have the `upgreek` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{extpfeil, upgreek}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ideal}\langle \rangle
\newcommand{\polyring}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\big[#2\big]}}

  \begin{document}

    \[ \polyring{\mathbb R}{x}_{/\ideal{x^2+1}}\xtofrom[\upbeta] {\enspace \upalpha\enspace }\mathbb C \]%

  \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Another possibility, with `tikz-cd`:

```
    \[ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
     \polyring{\mathbb R}{x}_{/\ideal{x^2+1}}\rar["\upalpha", shift left] & \mathbb C \lar["\upbeta", shift left]
    \end{tikzcd} \]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's almost what I needed, but I'd like the two arrows to be more spaced vertically, since when I print it to an A4 size PDF it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/GwaSA4s and you kind of not see the symbol very clearly.

Comment: I agree with you. It has the advantage of a simple syntax. Another solution would be to you use `tikz-cd` which gives the possibility to control the spacing, but the syntax is a bit more complex, but if you don't have to insert it in a wider set of equations, it's quite doable. B. t.w.,  where did you take this notation for quotient rings? It is not standard, as far as I know.

Comment: It is the notation our teacher used during the lectures. I'm just trying to make good and clean notes for me to study better without going crazy to find an information I need.

Comment: @Bafforasta: Please take a look at my edit, which uses the solution with `tikz-cd`.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great now!

Comment: @Bafforasta: Thank you for your kind appreciation. A last suggestion:  I thought  maybe, what your teacher  meant for the notation of a quotient structure is what one obtains with the `faktor` package.  You  should take a look at its (short) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for all your really useful suggestions, I'll definitely look into it.